# Does ExactTarget has it's own FTP?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does ExactTarget has its own FTP or does it use 'Enhanced FTP'? 
Also, please explain what is Enhanced FTP?

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant tags. This question has absolutely nothing to do with Salesforce1 or Salesforce DX.

Comment: I am new here. I tried adding Salesforce marketing cloud tag but it asked me some kind of reputation. Thanks for the tags. Although, you could have been a bit more humble. I don't know how this site works!

Comment: I apologize if I came across as rude, which certainly isn't my intent. We do have a nice [help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help) that can be useful in finding your bearings on SFSE. It can definitely be a bit overwhelming!

Answer (score 2):

Enhanced FTP just means SFTP in the Marketing Cloud world.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, sfmc uses third party ftp servers like file zilla & all for triggered automations?